# How to print an image from a webscraped URL in python

Tags: python, image-processing, web-scraping

I am building an image webscraper and I'm trying to display the image on screen. I've seen methods where you save the image to a file, however, I am wondering if there is a way to do it without saving the image to a file.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
def url_to_image(url):
    # download the image, convert it to a NumPy array, and then read
    # it into OpenCV format
    resp = requests.get(url)
    image = np.asarray(bytearray(res.json()['data'][0]['card_images'][0]['image_url'].encode()))
    image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    # return the image
    return image

print(url_to_image("https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api_internal/v7/cardinfo.php?&num=5000&offset=0&view=List&misc=yes"))
```

Comment: have you tried `cv2.imshow`?

Comment: you get `['image_url']` so it seems you have only url - why you convert url to numpy array? It is not image. Maybe use `print()` to check what you have in `['image_url']`. If it is really only url then you have to use `requests.get()` to read it. But it will be compressed `jpg` or `png` and you will have to uncompress it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you get `url` from `['image_url']` but you treat it as image.

You have to use again `requests.get()` with `url` from `['image_url']` to get image.

```
import requests
import numpy as np
import cv2

def url_to_image(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()
    
    image_url = data['data'][0]['card_images'][0]['image_url']
    print('image_url:', image_url)

    response = requests.get(image_url)
    
    data = np.asarray(bytearray(response.content), dtype="uint8")
    image = cv2.imdecode(data, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    
    cv2.imshow('image', image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    
    return image

print(url_to_image("https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api_internal/v7/cardinfo.php?&num=5000&offset=0&view=List&misc=yes"))
```